# Struggling to use upper and lower cases within my code

Tags: java

I can not find a way for the code to work with both upper and lower case letters, i can only find a way for it to run for one or the other... Been trying for a while and still haven't managed, pretty new to this you see! Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
public class LectureTimes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        char letter;
        System.out.println("Enter your class and" + " you will recieve your lecture time");

        do {
            letter = sc.next().charAt(0);
        } while (letter < 'a' || letter > 'd');

        if (letter == 'A') {
            System.out.println("Your class is at 10:00");
        } else {
            if (letter == 'a') {
                System.out.println("Your class is at 10:00");
            } else {
                if (letter == 'B') {
                    System.out.println("Your class is at 12:00");
                } else {
                    if (letter == 'b') {
                        System.out.println("Your class is at 12:00");
                    } else {
                    }
                    if (letter == 'C') {
                        System.out.println("Your class is at 14:00");
                    } else {
                        if (letter == 'c') {
                            System.out.println("Your class is at 14:00");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Your group does not exist, please select one that does...");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all, you should use switch case. or, get rid of all the else (remove the ladder and keep all ifs in same level)..

Comment: Also check out the `isUpperCase(char c)` and `isLowerCase(char c)` functions. Those should help out a lot. That being said, it looks like you don't care about upper or lower case (the classes are at the same time for each case of the same letter). If this is the case simply `toUpper` or `toLower` the character and check for A, B, or C (or a, b, or c).

Comment: can you try `while ((letter <'a' && letter > 'D') || letter < 'A' || letter > 'd');` .. not tested

Comment: You can first of all combine cases and don't need to nest the else case: `if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'a') { .. } else if (letter == 'B...`

Answer (score 6):

Since no one has posted the switch case solution yet, here it is:

```
switch (letter) {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            System.out.println("Your class is at 10:00");
            break;
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            System.out.println("Your class is at 12:00");
            break;
        case 'C':
        case 'c':
            System.out.println("Your class is at 14:00");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Your group does not exist, please select one that does...");
            break;
}
```

Personally, I find this to be the most readable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use `String` method `toUpperCase()` and check only for upper-case variants?

```
String myClass = (letter + "").toUpperCase();

    if (myClass.equals("A")) {
        System.out.println("Your class is at 10:00");
    } else {
        if (myClass.equals("B")) {
            System.out.println("Your class is at 12:00");
        } else
        if (myClass.equals("C")) {
            System.out.println("Your class is at 14:00");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your group does not exist, please select one that does...");
        }

    }
```

You also can use regex Pattern for this:

Comment: [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) has its own [`toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char)) and [`toUpperCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase(char)) methods.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know

Comment: Since you do the conversion to string, you might as well use `switch` rather than the if-else chain.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.toLowerCase()` or `String.toUpperCase()` methods.  Like

```
 if (letter.toLowerCase().equals("a")) {
       System.out.println("Your class is at 10:00");
 }
```

One more thing, use `equals()` method to check for equality!

Comment: so you may do like 
`String letter;
letter=sc.next().substring(0,1);`

Comment: Why not use [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) then?

Comment: it is another option))

Answer (score 1):

you can try changing the while loop like below. Your current loop is only checking `a` to `d`. Below loop will keep running if its

```
- < A
- > d
- between D and a
```

`do .. while((letter <'a' && letter > 'D') || letter < 'A' || letter > 'd');`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(letter == 'A' || letter == 'a'){
    System.out.println("Your class is at 10:00");
} else if(letter == 'B' || letter == 'b'){
    System.out.println("Your class is at 12:00");
} else if (letter == 'C' || letter == 'c'){
    System.out.println("Your class is at 14:00");
} else {
    System.out.println("Your group does not exist, please select one that does...")
}
```

this is my way to look your code cleaner and does not need to use String function which consume more resource.